# "one of a kind" vs "one of the kind"

Tags: articles, noun-phrases

It always made me wonder why we say "one of a kind" when usually the context allows the certainty

> I don't know how we'll ever replace Mary after she retires. She's really one of a kind. *= among the workers*

> In the world of ballet, she was one of a kind. *= among the ballet dancers*

> She's a very unusual woman, one of a kind. *= among women*

and clearly defines **the kind** we are talking about (= the group of people the subjects are unique within; whether it's workers, dancers, women)

My question is whether "one of the kind" is equally correct and as commonly used as "one of a kind". I couldn't find any entries in the dictionary or any good examples on the web. It does sound OK to my non-native ear. I am wondering why the native speaker would find it unnatural.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The sense is that there is a _special_ kind of workers/dancers/women and 'she' is the only one of that kind.

Comment: You've done research, and that's good. However, you've failed to heed what that research tells you, which is that "one of the kind" is not used at all. I agree with @KateBunting -- the phrase indicates uniqueness. She is the only one of that kind.

Comment: Sometimes idioms can't be taken literally, but you just repeat them, verbatim, without modification.   Isn't that the case here? "one of a kind" doesn't exactly make sense.   Perhaps if you include more words: "She is the only one in existence, of a very special kind of person."